# How to add RabbitMQ library to project? 'The import "com.rabbitmq" cannot be resolved'

Tags: java, eclipse, rabbitmq

I am working through the RabbitMQ Java tutorial found here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html

I have downloaded the Java Client Library package, and copied the JAR files to my project in Eclipse, but the import statements

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
```

all yield the error

```
The import "com.rabbitmq" cannot be resolved.
```

The instructions are unclear how to incorporate the JAR files from the Java Client Library package, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download the **rabbitmq-java-client-bin-3.5.4.zip** from official link [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.5.4/rabbitmq-java-client-bin-3.5.4.zip) . Then extract the **rabbitmq-client.jar** from the zip & add it to your class path in project. Then you will be able to resolve `The import "com.rabbitmq"`. Give it a try.

Comment: I have the dependency in my pom.xml. This should get automatically added to the project's class path right? When I give, `mvn clean compile`, I don't get any errors. I am not able to run the project from cmd by giving `ampq-client-4.0.2.jar file1.java file2.java`. What's going wrong here? Should I also manually download the jar and add it to my class path?

Answer (score 0):

Since the verified answer doesn't work anymore, here is my solution:

You can download the **amqp-client-5.8.0.jar** from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/rabbitmq/amqp-client/5.8.0/amqp-client-5.8.0.jar) . Then add it to your class path, like any other jar.

In case that the link doesn't work, you can manually download it from [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-client.html) or even add the required dependency to your maven/gradle project.

Comment: @Ankit Nigam's answer is still valid. Just validated now with IntelliJ.

Comment: @LorenzoBattilocchi Interesting. It might had to do with the version of Java the individual uses, since the other answer is old enough.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual studio code(vscode) we need to add the library file under Referenced Libraries [enter image description here](https://i.stack) under the Java projects section.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMV7k.png).imgur.com/txB2s.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).